# Problem with POST->REDIRECT->GET pattern in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I'm trying do make simple rules page in ASP .NET webpages(using C#, which shows all rules (list of strings) and let You add next, immediately adding them to those already printed. (Its just for educational purpouse) 
I know I should to this with POST->REDIRECT->GET pattern and storing list of strings in session data, though I can get how exactly I should acces those data - anything I tried ended just in errors, like: code error CS1002: ; expected at line 40 (which is strange, because I checked this line and others too and I didn't find any missing semicolons... I think it may be caused by some of the code working differently that I expected...)

Here's one version of the code I tried:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var rules = new List<string>();
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



    <form action="~/Rules.cshtml" method="Post">
        <p>
            <label for="name">New rule</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="rule">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add"></p>
        </p>
    </form>

    @{
        if (Session["rules"] == null)
        {

            Session["rules"] = rules;
        }

        if (IsPost)
        {
                rules = new List<string>();
                foreach (var i in (List<string>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Session["rules"])
                {
                    rules.Add(i);
                }
                rules.Add(Request.Form["rule"]);
                List<string>System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Session["rules"] = rules;
            }

        }

    }


    <ul>
        @{ foreach (var x in Request.Session["rules"])
            {
                <li>@x</li>
            }

        }
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Rules.cshtml is obviously file with this code.
(I know, that recreating whole list every time isn't most optimal solution, but I didn't find any way to do it differently... If You have some solution I'm open to advices)

Comment: Which one is line 40?

Comment: There's a curly brace `}` too much; remove that one on line 40 or the one above.

Comment: Line 40 is this: List<string>System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Session["rules"] = rules;
An right it was one curly bracket to much, though... deleting it didn't solve the problem. Now I get:
CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
(I don't gettin where I'm supposed to add a colon? Or colon in single quotes...)

Comment: The `List<string>` at the beginning of that line 40 shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
After deleting this and cutting all before "Sesion["rules"]" and adding casting to list in last loop it started to work! 
Though after refreshing the page the last entry of the form is added again... how to avoid this?